# Can’t observe AVPlayerItem for @“status” key

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I’m trying to play stream from URL, but here is an issue. ObserveValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context just doesn’t execute. As I understand, it is not depends on streamURL, nether it is correct or not. It must change status to AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay or AVPlayerItemStatusFailed from AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown. But nonetheless I checked that URL in browser, and it is working fine. So, what’s the problem? I watched WWDC video about it, and it says, if you have audio stream, use AVPLayerItem *before* AVAsset.

Here is my code:

```
- (void) prepare
{
    NSURL * trackStreamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:streamURL];
    NSLog(@"STREAM URL: %@",trackStreamURL);
    _playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:trackStreamURL];
    [_playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"KEY PATH    : %@", keyPath);
    NSLog(@"CHANGE      : %@", change);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always observed the `status`  property on the `AVPlayer` instead of the `AVPlayerItem` since you need a player to play the player item anyway. In fact, I had never even looked at the status property of the player item.

The status of the player item probably never changes because there is no player that is ready to play it. So, Create a player with the player item and observe the status of the player (or possibly, still the status of the player item).

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

Comment: I followed wwdc video, it says I can observe playerItem property. Also apple doc says the same. But your solution works. Thanks.

Comment: You are right that the player item has a status property but I have always observed the status of the player. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The video says that, but also says that you should add the player before waiting for status changes. As said above, setting the player will start start the loading process.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I am trying to play HLS package in offline mode. I have set observer for both playerItem and player status but observer is not getting called. can you suggest something for this?